# epoll triggered the read event but could not read the data?

Tags: c++, linux, http, networking

I am using C++to write an http server program under Linux. When using epoll triggered by ET to trigger the read event for the first time, I read the correct data. The socket will never read any information after triggering the read event for the second time.

The same socket in the program received two http requests. The first is the request for the home page. The data was successfully received and processed. The second is the request of favicon.ico, which also triggers a read event, but never reads any data.

This is the code of the server side

```
void Server::serverListen()
{
    int listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    assert(listenfd >= 0);
 
    sockaddr_in addr;
    bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 
    int tmp = 1;
    setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &tmp, sizeof(tmp));
 
    int ret = bind(listenfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    assert(ret >= 0);
 
    ret = listen(listenfd, 5);
    assert(ret >= 0);
 
    int epollfd = epoll_create(5);
    assert(epollfd != -1);
    epoll_event events;
    events.data.fd = listenfd;
    events.events = EPOLLIN;
    int n = epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listenfd, &events);
    assert(n != -1);
    epoll_event eve[10000];
    while (true)
    {
        int num = epoll_wait(epollfd, eve, 10000, -1);
        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        {
            int fd = events.data.fd;
            if (fd == listenfd)
            {
                sockaddr_in caddr;
                socklen_t tmplen = sizeof(caddr);
 
                connfd = accept(listenfd, (sockaddr*)&caddr, &tmplen);
                assert(connfd != -1);
 
                int flag = fcntl(connfd, F_GETFL);
                flag |= O_NONBLOCK;
                fcntl(connfd, F_SETFL, flag);
 
                epoll_event even;
                events.data.fd = connfd;
                events.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
                int n = epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &even);
                assert(n != -1);
            }
            else
            {
                worker.work(connfd, epollfd);
            }
        }
 
    }
    //Why do I still run here even though I write a dead loop program?
    //When I step into debugging, the program returns to the loop after running these two statements, so I commented them out
    //When I keep them, the program returns to the loop after running them and continues to trigger the first read event, which makes me unable to read any data even for the first read event
    //close(epollfd);
    //close(listenfd);
}
```

This is part of the code of the read data function

```
void Worker::work(const int& connfd, const int& epollfd)
{
    int len = 0,totle = 0;
    char buf[40960]{ '0' };
    char temp[40960]{ '0' };
 
    while ((len = recv(connfd, temp, sizeof(temp), NULL)) > 0)
    {
        if (totle + len < sizeof(buf))
        {
            memcpy(buf + totle, temp, len);
        }
        totle += len;
    }
    std::cout << "len:" << len << std::endl << "buf:" << buf << std::endl;
    if (len == -1 && errno == EAGAIN)
    {
        int ll = 0;
        parser.getLine(buf, tline);
        std::cout << "tline:" << tline << std::endl;
        parser.getStatus(tline, tstatus);
        parser.getFile(tline, tfile);
    //Omit the logic processing code after reading
    }
}
```

Result of the first request

```
len:-1
buf:GET / HTTP/1.1
 
Host: 192.168.10.150:10000
 
Connection: keep-alive
 
Cache-Control: max-age=0
 
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.69
 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
 
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6


num:820
```

Result of the second request

```
len:-1
buf:0
```

I can make sure that the problem occurs in epoll, because when I don't use epoll, the program works well. (Except that the loop will still be skipped, I don't understand what happened)

I used ET trigger.

Buf and temp are sufficient for my program, because only 820 bytes of data were read for the first time.

The socket passed to the work function twice is the same.

The first read event was successfully triggered and read. The second read event was triggered but no data was readable.

So why can't I read any data for the second time? Isn't the read event triggered?

And why does my program jump out of that loop?

Comment: When and where do you check the returning events in the **`eve`** array?

Comment: Also, when and where do you check for `epoll_wait` failures?

Comment: Unrelated: Why have an array of 10000 `epoll_event`? Wouldn't it be enough to make it as big as the number of file descriptors? `std::vector<epoll_event> eve(no_fds);`

Comment: epoll triggering semantics are difficult to get right. I take the cheap and easy way out: make all sockets that I poll non-blocking, and implement the usual non-blocking semantics when reading or writing to them, in response to epoll events. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm at epoll_ After wait (epollfd, eve, 10000, - 1), add the assert function and try to output the value of eve [0]. data.fd. The value of num is not - 1, but epoll_ ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, connfd, &even); There is a problem. It returns - 1. The value of eve [0]. data.fd output before the program terminates is the value of listenfd. After I delete the newly added output line code, the program can run again. After that, each time it is triggered is the connfd after the same accept function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, it shouldn't be so big. I will modify it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude epoll_ Wait returns one fd as listenfd for the first time, and two fds for the second time. The first is still listenfd, and the second is 0. It seems that there is no fd with 0 in my program

Comment: The events returned are in `eve`. You need to check `eve[i]` for what happened, not `events`. Like shown in [the `epoll(7)` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) example.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have basically solved the problem. Except for favicon.ico, I still cannot return, but I will find a way. I made a series of low-level mistakes. Due to the lack of differentiated naming, I mistakenly used different variables in the code, and mistakenly used outdated fd instead of eve [i]. data. fd.

Comment: In the code that is calling `recv()`, you are waiting for `recv()` to fail and then using `EAGAIN` to trigger parsing of `buf`. That is completely wrong logic. You need to actually parse the received data according to the HTTP syntax in order to detect the end of the request (or at least the end of the request headers). You can get `EAGAIN` without having a full request yet. Also, you are treating `buf` as a null-terminated string, but `buf` is not null-terminated after `recv()` exits. Also, you are incrementing `totle` even if you don't copy bytes into `buf`